# Twitter login issue Parse.com iOS

Tags: ios, twitter, parse-platform

I recently deleted all the multiple duplicate files from my mac and that messed up my xcode project. I had to import all the twitter frameworks again and had to delete the twitter run script for my app to work. Before my mess up everything worked fine.

Now everytime i login into with twitter this error comes up `TWTRLogInButton was created with no completionBlock set`

my code that worked perfectly:

```
- (IBAction)twlogin:(TWTRLogInButton *)sender {

        [PFTwitterUtils logInWithBlock:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
        }
        else {
            PF_Twitter *twitter = [PFTwitterUtils twitter];
            PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
            NSString *twitterScreenName = twitter.screenName;
            [[PFUser currentUser] setObject:twitterScreenName forKey:@"username"];
            [user saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error)
             {
                 if (error)
                 {
                     UIAlertView *alertVeiw = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sorry" message:[error.userInfo objectForKey:@"error"] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
                     [alertVeiw show];
                 }

                 else {
                     [[PFInstallation currentInstallation] setObject:[PFUser currentUser].objectId forKey:@"userId"];
                     [[PFInstallation currentInstallation] saveInBackground];

                     [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
                 }
             }];

            [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
        }
    }];
}
```

Please help me fix my issue.

Comment: This is kind of off topic but also relevant. Just want to check that you're aware that Parse is shutting down and anything you write on the Parse back end will stop working in just under a year's time.

Comment: Also, you're using the button incorrectly. It manages the login to Twitter itself. You can then respond to the completion and log in to Parse if you wish. You shouldn't be using the button to login to Parse though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there may be a bug in the Parse Twitter SDK. Many people are having this problem today. check this link https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/914545211986956/

Answer (score 0):

You may be defining the button in the storyboard or xib file, and the `completionBlock` needs to be set programmatically. If you define it in the storyboard and your `viewDidLoad`, the app is probably presenting the button from the storyboard. So, in `viewDidLoad`, define it:

```
self.myTwitterLoginButton.logInCompletion = ^(TWTRSession *session, NSError *error) {
    /* your code */
};
```

Edit:

In addition, don't hook up the `twlogin` action event in the storyboard. Your current action will end up in the completion block. Do hook the button up to an IBOutlet property and do not recreate it. In my code above, the IBOutlet is to myTwitterLoginButton.

Comment: Do you have it hooked up in your storyboard to the IBOutlet? You may be referencing two different buttons.

Comment: yes everything is hooked up but i deleted files from my mac and had to add all the frameworks back in and they are referenced in another file so not fabric run script has error

Comment: @Joey121 you can't hook up an action to the button. You need to unhook the IBAction from the button.

Comment: Thats it. You should hook it up by IBOutlet, unhook the action, and specify the action in viewDidLoad as shown above.

Comment: @PeterDeWeese yep. Not the action though. The completion block :D You can't have any action on this button. It has a built in action of "log in to Twitter" and then once the action is complete it will run the completion block.